# the paxos in chubby

Tags: paxos

In chubby the process of each log that write to db is one instance of the paxos process, and this instance may have many proposers, so it will have a master selected process.
why it has many proposers?

Answer (score 1):

Having a single leader (aka a "Distinguished Proposer") is an optimization for Paxos. The whole point of Paxos is to decide a value when there are multiple proposers proposing different things.

The whole point of having multiple proposers is in case the "Distinguished Proposer" fails; something has to pick up that new role. Paxos, when it decides a value, implicitly decides between proposers.

As in your other question, I suggest looking at the other Paxos questions, perhaps read *Paxos Made Simple.*